# Mac admin account deleted -- have I lost my files?

Tags: user-account, data-recovery, administrator

I got a new computer and gave my old one to my wife. Before I had a chance to save some files she deleted my admin account and set up one for herself.

How do I get my old files off the computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do after I lost my MacBook data?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54953/what-should-i-do-after-i-lost-my-macbook-data)

Comment: Was the admin account the one you used to work with and stored your files in? What was your backup strategy?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options given when deleting an account on a Mac:

- Save the home folder as a disk image: This will archive all the
  user’s documents and information so the user can be restored later if
  needed. The disk    image is saved in /Users/Deleted Users/.
- Leave the user’s home folder as is: Select “Don’t change the home
  folder.” The user’s documents and information remain and the user can
  be restored later if needed. The home folder remains in /Users/.
- Remove the user’s home folder from the computer: Select “Delete the
  home folder.” The user information will be deleted and the storage
  space will be freed. If you want to prevent programs that read raw
  data from retrieving any files, select “Erase home folder securely.”

If she chose the second option, to save the home folder, you might still have your files. Are you comfortable using terminal? If so, you can navigate to the users/ folder and see if you see your old username and if anything is in there. If there is, you can use some commands to move the files onto the desktop

```
cd /Users
ls -l
sudo mv -r [username] ~/Desktop
```

If she chose the first option, then cd/Users/"Deleted Users" instead of /Users.
If she chose the third option, that's beyond what I know to do. Either way, check those two folders.